# Getting a path from list of arcs in C++

Tags: c++

We are given a vector of `std::pair<int, int>`s, `start` int and `stop` int, and I need to extract the path out of it.

For instance:
given `start = 2`, `stop = 8` and list of `std::pair`s as `[(0, 5) (6,8), (5,6), (2,0)]`. I am ordering the vector into:
`[(2,0), (0,5), (5,6), (6,8)]`. Now I need to isolate the nodes to get the path as `[2,0,5,6,8]`. (i.e. `(2,0)` and `(0,5)` become `[2,0,5]` and so on).

I have the following code. It works but I feel that it is needlessly long. Any idea to make it more compact and "safe"?

```
std::vector<int> get_pretty_path(const std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>& path_arcs, int s, int t){

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> ordered_arcs;


    assert(path_arcs.size() > 0);

    int _s = s;
    int _t = t;

    bool l_flag= true;

    std::vector<int> path;

    while (l_flag) {
        for(auto &arc: path_arcs){
            if (arc.first == _s){
                ordered_arcs.push_back(arc);
                _s = arc.second;
                if(arc.second == _t){
                    l_flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if(ordered_arcs.size() == 1){
        path.push_back(ordered_arcs.begin()->first);
        path.push_back(ordered_arcs.begin()->second);
    }
    else if (ordered_arcs.size() == 2){
        for (auto it = ordered_arcs.begin(); it != ordered_arcs.end()-1; ++it){
            if (it->second == (it+1)->first){
                path.push_back(it->first);
                path.push_back(it->second);
            }

            if((it+1) == ordered_arcs.end()-1){
                path.push_back((it+1)->second);
            }
        }
    }
    else{

        for (auto it = ordered_arcs.begin(); it != ordered_arcs.end()-1; ++it){
            if (it->second == (it+1)->first){
                path.push_back(it->first);
            }
            if((it+1) == ordered_arcs.end()-1){
                path.push_back((it+1)->first);
                path.push_back((it+1)->second);
            }
        }
    }

    return path;
}
```

This function is called in the order of 10,000 times. I was wondering if it can be as fast as possible. The max length of `path_arcs` is around 7-8 but is is usually 4-5 or less.

Note that the paths are not weighted. There is only one path. I just need it to be ordered from `start` to `end`. Some more examples:

```
input = [(2,0)] // given by the user
start = 2       // given by the user
stop = 0        // given by the user
output = [2,0]  // This should be the output

input = [(1,4), (2,1)] // given by the user
start = 2              // given by the user
stop = 4               // given by the user
output = [2,1,4]

input = [(4,5),(7,4),(2,3),(5,2)] // given by the user
start = 7                         // given by the user
stop =  3                         // given by the user
output = [7,4,5,2,3]
```

Comment: You should probably explain what the code is supposed to do. *... The path is [2,0,5,6,8].* Why?

Comment: Hello! The start is 2 and the end is 8. so we need to go through each of the arc in the list and get the path.

Comment: The question is better now, but there are still some questions: if the arcs are edges in a (non-weighted?) graph, then which path do you want? Any path, or path with least amount of arcs? It would be great to have a runnable example (something we could paste in e.g. [wandbox.org](wandbox.org) to try out and play with it). Otherwise the question sounds good, just needs a bit more elaboration on the description.

Comment: @Incomputable I added more info.

Comment: _`(2,0)` and `(0,5)` become `[2,5]`_ - it should become `[2,0,5]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @vnp. You are right

Answer (score 3):

The key is to create a mapping for the edges:

```
vector<int>
get_pretty_path(const vector<pair<int,int>>& edges, int s, int t) {
    map<int,int> edgeMap = {begin(edges), end(edges)};
    vector<int> path;
    while (s != t) {
        path.push_back(s);
        s = edgeMap[s];
    }
    path.push_back(s);
    return path;
}
int main() {
    const vector<pair<int,int>> edges{{4, 5}, {7, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 2}};
    const vector<int> path = get_pretty_path(edges, 7, 3);
    for (auto i : path) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code assumes `using namespace std;` which is sometimes frowned
upon but which I think is fine for small examples. The code will bug
out if you can't walk from `s` to `t` or if more than one edge starts
at a given node index. If such situations can happen, you have to decide
how to best handle them.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to profile it against my implementation as this function is called lot of times.

Comment: You should pass `edges` by *const* reference. But this is a clean solution. (I added some consts to your solution; feel free to flag my comment as "no longer needed").